# How to add custom method to Lumen's response class

Tags: laravel, lumen, lumen-5.4

I'm using response method `withHeaders()`:

```
return response(view('pages.top.index', compact('data')))->withHeaders(['one-param' => 'data', 'second-param' => 'data2' ...);
```

And I have multiple same params that I put in `withHeaders()` method almost in every Controller's action. Is there a way I can add my own method and chain it like:

```
return response(view('pages.top.index', compact('data')))->customMethod('data', 'data2', ....);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Response is macroable so you can add this to the service provider:

```
\Illuminate\Http\Response::macro('customMethod', function () { 
      //Method body
      return $this; //To chain it
});
```

Note: 
I tend to avoid this because it gives my IDE a very hard time with type-hinting .

If the problem is with needing to pass the same data over and over again you might also consider [sharing data with all views](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/views#sharing-data-with-all-views)

Comment: For Lumen 5.7, the call is `\Laravel\Lumen\Http\ResponseFactory::macro`